# Anti ping system. Working depends on which one is on top

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm having a problem with my anti ping system. It works alone, but with the other stuff (If (data) ... } else if (!data) {...) they overlap. If I add the if (comrade) on top of the if (data), other commands stop working but the anti ping works. Here is my code (also I get no errors):

```
const pinger = new Set();
const pinged = new Set();

client.on('message', async (message) => {

    const data = await prefix.findOne({
        GuildID: message.guild.id
    });

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

    const messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    const cmd = messageArray[0];
    const args = messageArray.slice(1);

    if (data) {
        const prefix = data.Prefix;

        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
        const commandfile = client.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length).toLowerCase() || client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length).toLowerCase())));
        commandfile.run(client, message, args);

    } else if (!data) {
        const prefix = "!";

        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
        const commandfile = client.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length).toLowerCase() || client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length).toLowerCase())));
        commandfile.run(client, message, args);
    }

    let comrade = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())
    let mrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'dont ping again');
    let comradeid = message.guild.members.cache.get(comrade.user.id);
    let authorid = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id);

    if (comrade) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (pinger.has(authorid), pinged.has(comradeid)) {

            message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(f => {
                f.overwritePermissions([{
                  id: mrole.id,
                  deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
                }]);
              })

              authorid.roles.add(mrole)
              setTimeout(() => {
                  authorid.roles.remove(mrole)
              }, 30000)

              embed.setTitle('BRUH')
              embed.setDescription('YOU CANT MASS PING THAT PERSON')
              embed.setColor('RED')
              message.channel.send(embed)

        } else {
            if (!mrole) message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: 'dont ping again' } });
            if (comrade.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'dont ping me')) {

            pinged.add(comradeid)
            setTimeout(() => {
                pinged.delete(comradeid)
            }, 15000)
            pinger.add(authorid)
            setTimeout(() => {
               pinger.delete(authorid)
            }, 15000);
            
          }
        }
    }
})
```

It uses a mongoDB (database) because I want my bot to have a change its prefix for other guilds command (which works perfectly). Here the commands work (the if (data) where it checks for a prefix), but the anti pinging system doesn't. I've tried a lot of stuff, but they end up not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if (data) ... else if (!data)` is unnecessary. If `data` is not true, then `!data` will be true and no further test is necessary.

Comment: also `if (pinger.has(authorid), pinged.has(comradeid))` almost certainly does not mean what you think it does. The result of the first `.has()` test is ignored.

Comment: Finally, but basically, it's not at all clear what "anti ping system" means.

Comment: sorry im new to discord.js, also the anti ping is just if someone pings more than once it creates a role that then overwrites permission to the channel and the person cant talk for 30 seconds, when the 30 seconds pass it removes the muted role.

Comment: also about the ```if (pinger.has(authordid), pinged.has(comradeid))```. I didnt think it would work but it did when I tested it lmao

Comment: well it's not a syntax error but the result of the first `.has()` test will be completely ignored. That's a *comma expression* and the only important part is the part after the last comma.